# Convert HttpContext.User before API Method

Tags: api, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I currently have a .Net Core API application with a bunch of API get methods. Currently in every single method I am needing to write this line:

```
        [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(MetadataAttributeModel))]
        [ProducesResponseType(400, Type = typeof(ValidationResultModel))]
        [ProducesResponseType(500, Type = typeof(ErrorResultModel))]
        public ActionResult<MetadataAttributeModel> GetAsync(string name)
        {
            List<Entities.DocumentAttributeView> attributes = documentAttributeViewRepo.GetByAttributeName(name);

            SiteUser currentUser = new SiteUser(db, User.FindFirst("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress").Value);

            return Unauthorized();
        }
```

Is there a way I can convert the HttpContext.User object to our own SiteUser object before I get to the method? I don't want to have to write this line in ALL of the API methods:

```
 SiteUser currentUser = new SiteUser(db, HttpContext.User.FindFirst("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress").Value);
```

TIA,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AspNet Mvc mechanism for "Do something for every Action" is [Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Filters can run before the method is called, and they can, for instance, set the `Http.Context.User`.

A filter can be applied to an action, a controller, or (by writing code in `Startup`) globally.

```
[SwapUserToAuthorizedDatabaseUser]
public class MyController
{
    public IActionResult About() => Ok(User);
}
```

Which will invoke this filter for every Action on the Controller :

```
public class SwapUserToAuthorizedDatabaseUserAttribute : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        SiteUser currentUser = new SiteUser(db, User.FindFirst("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress").Value);
        if (currentUser == null)
        {
            context.Result= new RedirectToRouteResult("/Identity/Logout");
        }
        else
        {
            var claimsIdentity =
                new ClaimsIdentity(
                    new Claim[]
                    {
                        new Claim("Id", currentUser.Id),
                        new Claim("UserName", currentUser.UserName),
                        new Claim("WhateverElseYourSiteUserHas", currentUser.Something.ToString()),
                    }
                );
            context.HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[]{claimsIdentity});
        }
    }
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context){}
}
```

If overwriting the `HttpContext.User` isn't what you need, then it's much less code to use `HttpContext.Items` :

```
public class SwapUserToAuthorizedDatabaseUserAttribute : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Items["SiteUser"]= new SiteUser(db, User.FindFirst("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress").Value);
    }
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context){}
}
```

Instead of an `IActionFilter` to run on every Action, you can use an `IAuthorizationFilter` which has a `public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)` method. This would save repeatedly calling the database, but does mean you must cache your `currentUser` somewhere, presumably in `Session`.

The problem is, how do you get access to your database? If you go the route of adding a Global filter by adding it in Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services
            .AddMvc(o=>o.Filters.Add(new SwapUserToAuthorizedDatabaseUserAttribute(provide a db instance here)));
}
```

Then you can give your Filter a constructor and pass in a database. There's also an overload for using the DependencyInjection system.

If you don't use the startup method, you have to do some DIY injection, for instance by having a static method to return a `DbContext`.

Answer (score 0):

You can move this logic to a service:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly HttpContext context;
    private readonly Db db;

    public UserService(IHttpContextAccessor context, Db db)
    {
        this.context = context.HttpContext;
        this.db = db;
    }

    public SiteUser GetUser()
    {
        return new SiteUser(db, context.User.FindFirst("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress").Value);
    }
}
```

Inject it to controllers where it's required:

```
public MyController(IUserService userService) { ... }
```

Register it as a Scoped service in ConfigureServices in Startup.cs along with `IHttpContextAccessor` (should be singleton):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<UserService>();
    services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}
```